# A determined duck is following me

Tags: support

Everywhere where I go, there's a duck in the bottom right corner, just staring at me.

**Why is it there? When did they implement it?**

Answer (score 7):

It's an April Fool's joke, and it's April 1 somewhere in the world.

See the Meta Stack Exchange question [Stack Exchange has been taken over by a rubber duck!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308564/157730), particularly [Rishav's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/308578/157730) to that question.

You can get rid of it by telling it that you have a microphone (no, it won't actually use one), then wait for a while until you get the choice between "I have another problem" and "I hate this duck". Click "I hate this duck", and it disappears. That answer also tells you how to get it back if you for some reason change your mind.

For me personally, this is probably the first Stack Exchange April Fool's joke that I've sincerely found annoying or, at the very least, overly intrusive. (They could at least have made it into an alternative site search input field or *something*, to encourage good behavior instead of just annoying people...)

Comment: You can also say "No" when it asks for the microphone. It will still go through the same procedure and allow you to say "I hate this duck" at the end.

Comment: @Secespitus I tried saying no. Guess I got annoyed by the fact that it went through the motions anyway. At least I was able to get rid of it.